# Call javaScript function in jsp code, or close window in jsp code?

Tags: jsp

This my code I try

```
 <%
 ....jsp code
call javascript function close()?????
 %>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 function close()
{
 window.close();  
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a better way to do this... But if you output an element with your scriptlet, and then see if that element exists...

```
<% out.println( "<div id='close'>Can you see this</div>" ); %>

<script type="text/javascript">

     alert( document.getElementById("close").innerHTML );

     if ( document.getElementById("close") )
     {
         window.close();
     }
</script>
```

Comment: @FrankSharp I updated the code, tell me if it's printing the "can you see this" to the page...

Comment: @FrankSharp try my code again, we're now alerting the innerHTML of the div.. So you should get an alert box with "can you see this" text inside.